# Remove SKU from quote admin order item

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer, quote

I have Observer Written for admin order i want to remove one product item from my admin cart list i have added 3-4 products i have my product name : test i want to remove that test

i have added 2 products in my order cart from that 2 products i want to remove 1 product i will create one coupon code once admin apply that coupon then test1 product should remove from order item list i have not placed the order i just added to order item list

```
<sales_quote_item_set_product>
    <observers>
        <namespace_removeproduct_order_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>additionalproduct/observer</class>
            <method>removeProduct</method>
        </namespace_removeproduct_order_observer>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

observer.php

```
public function removeProduct($observer)
{
}
```

Comment: Hello, your question is not clear at all. You want to remove a product from the cart or from an existing order?

Comment: @ranjeev : yes s

Comment: @ranjeev : i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change event to `salesrule_validator_process` *(and flush cache)*.

If coupon code `your_coupon_code` is applied the product with SKU `test1` is removed from your order:

```
public function removeProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($observer->getRule()->getCouponCode() == 'your_coupon_code') {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == 'test1') {
                $quote->deleteItem($item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working i have added 2 products in my order cart from that 2 products i want to remove 1 product i will create one coupon code once admin apply that coupon then test1 product should remove from order item list i have not placed the order i just added to order item list

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCouponCode() on null in

Comment: Have you changed event to `salesrule_validator_process` and flushed cache? Code is tested.

Comment: yes its working now but there is one issue we are not able to track that applied coupon in order why ?

Comment: What do you mean? Think this isnt related to the original question.

Comment: applied coupon is not showing in order but its working you can try to place order with that coupon code then try to find out that coupon in your order you will not able to find

Comment: I can see it order totals `Discount(myCouponCode)  -100 $`. If it does not work, please ask a new question - seems not related to this question.

Comment: please set discount amount 0 & check we are using that coupon with 0 price to remove the product only but its show somewhere in order because that coupon has applied successfully it will be really appreciate if you will check once

Comment: Seems correct to me. If there isn't any discounted ammount, nothing needs to show up. You can (programmtically) add an order comment therefor.

Comment: Products is removed Successfully by applying coupon code but that product amount is still showing on grand total

Comment: see here i raised new one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180415/admin-order-item-remove-product-by-coupon-code-not-updating-grand-total