# Admin order Item remove Product by coupon code not updating grand total

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer

I am trying to remove Product by applying zero price coupon code its working fine but Grand total is not updating on apply the coupon code . its working if I click on update items button.

I have added 2 products test1 => price : $100 & test2 => price => $10 
On apply coupon code, test2 is removed from order item from admin but grand total is showing $110 its should show $100 only . if i click on update button its showing correct one.

what I want on apply coupon code it should show the $100

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_additionalproduct_order_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>additionalproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>addProduct</method>
                    </namespace_additionalproduct_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>

            <salesrule_validator_process>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_removeproduct_order_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>additionalproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>removeProduct</method>
                    </namespace_removeproduct_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_validator_process>

        </events>
    </adminhtml>

Observer.php

        public function addProduct($observer)
        {

            $hessSkuTwentySeventeen = '2017MiniCollection';
            $hessSkuServiceFee = 'ServiceFee';
            $added = false;
            $quote = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $product = $observer->getProduct();

            if ($product->getSku() == $hessSkuTwentySeventeen) {
                $addProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $addProduct->load($addProduct->getIdBySku($hessSkuServiceFee));

                foreach ($quote->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == $hessSkuTwentySeventeen) {
                        $added = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!$added) {
                    $quote->getQuote()->addProduct($addProduct);
                }
            }
        }

        public function removeProduct($observer){
            $hessSkuServiceFee = 'ServiceFee';

            if ($observer->getRule()->getCouponCode() == 'removeproduct') {
                $quote = $observer->getQuote();
                foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == $hessSkuServiceFee) {
                        $quote->deleteItem($item);


                    }
                }
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing function called `collectTotals()`.

try this: `$quote->collectTotals()->save();`

This should update total.

For more info you can visit function `collectTotals()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` class. Which goes to each items and updates the total and other stuff. It's very important to call `collectTotals()` after each `quote` update.